# Silverlight Button Style gets stuck on fullscreen

Tags: silverlight, templates, styles

So I have a number of buttons in Silverlight that I've made from images. In each case the button has a regular image and a hover image. I've used Blend to have the hover image fade in over .15 seconds on hover.

**The problem with this is that I can't figure out how to access the images anymore, since they are embedded in the style.** So, I have a separate style for each button, instead of a single UserControl with two interchangable images.

Also I have a set of two buttons: FullScreen and ExitFullScreen. The hover image gets stuck in this case:

1. Press fullscreen. The exit fullscreen button is now in a different place.
2. Press exit fullscreen. The fullscreen button is back in the original place. The hover animation is displayed, even though the mouse is not over the button.

Code:-

```
<Style x:Key="ExitFullScreenButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.1500000" To="MouseOver"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Duration="00:00:00.0010000" Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Image Source="Images/ControlBar/exitFullScreenButton.png"/>
                            <Image x:Name="image" Opacity="0" Source="Images/ControlBar/exitFullScreenButtonHover.png"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Full Screen"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>


<Button x:Name="ExitFullScreenButton" Click="ExitFullScreenButton_Click" Canvas.Top="14"
                  Style="{StaticResource ExitFullScreenButton}" 
                  Width="32" Content="Button" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making a user control and doing the animation in code.

```
private Storyboard hoverAnimation = new Storyboard();

private void CreateAnimation()
        {
            SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;

            Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150));
            hoverAnimation.Duration = duration;

            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.Duration = duration;
            hoverAnimation.Children.Add(animation);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, HoverIcon);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));

            animation.To = 1;
        }
```